# Filter dataframe by factor after selected input in server

Tags: r, shiny

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) which are identical. I want a shiny app were the user firstly select one of the dataframes and secondly filter by a specific column value (in the example data the column `region`) and get a table in return. I manage to achieve the first task but can't seem to figure out how to do the second one. I have made several attempts with the combination of `reactive` and `filter` without any success. I have made a comment in the script below were I made the attempts.

```
library(shiny)
#Dataset
names_df1 <- c("Henry","Charles","Lisa","Jessica","Steven","Ali","Mona","Patricia","George","John") 
region_df1 <- sample(c("North","West","East","South"),10,replace=T)
df1 <- data.frame(names_df1,region_df1)

names_df2 <- c("Michael","Simone","Anna","Steven","Billie","Emma","Maria","Gordon","Bruce","Rachel") 
region_df2 <- sample(c("North","West","East","South"),10,replace=T)
df2 <- data.frame(names_df2,region_df2)

colnames(df1) <- c("Names","Region")
colnames(df2) <- c("Names","Region")

ui <- fluidPage(
  

  titlePanel("Shiny Text"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                  label = "df1/df2:",
                  choices = c("df1", "df2")),
      
      selectInput("region",
                  "Region:",
                c("All","North","West","East","South")),
        
      numericInput(inputId = "obs",
                   label = "Number of observations to view:",
                   value = 20)),

        mainPanel(
          tableOutput("view")
        )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #Chose input
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "df1" = df1,
           "df2" = df2)
  })
  
  #Do I filter here?
  
  
  #Render table
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anybody give me some directions?
Best/John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like that:

```
  #Render table
  output$view <- renderTable({
    out <- datasetInput()
    if (input$region != "All") {
      out <- out[out$Region == input$region, ]
    }
    head(out, n = input$obs)
  })
```